# Array.prototype.includes - not transformed with babel

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I cannot figure out how to get this code to transform to compatible code in Node.js v4 env: `[].includes('anything')`

Becuase this throws an error in Node.js v4 `Error: includes is not a function...`

Can anyone help me understand why `babel` does not transform `.includes()`? I have tried using babel-preset-es2015 and babel-preset-es2016 as well as the babel repl: [Example babel repl code usage](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2016&targets=Node-4.0&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%5B%5D.includes('test'))

Comment: Because it is polyfillable. Polyfillable features are not transpiled.

Comment: You need a polyfill to include the ES6 methods like `.includes()`.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: Im using this code in a library that is consumed by a webpack project. When I used the babel-polyfill and include the library in the webpack project which also uses the babel-polyfill, I get an error that babel-polyfill can only be included once. Can anyone recommend a solution where my library can use a polyfill that does not conflict with any project that require it in their package/bundle?

Answer (score 1):

You need to import babel-polyfill to use static methods like `Array.from` or `Object.assign`, instance methods like `Array.prototype.includes`.

If you don't want to modify globals, checkout the transform-runtime plugin. This means you won't be able to use the instance methods mentioned above like `Array.prototype.includes`.