# Webpack4 not compile the webpack bootstrap code to es5?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

the code of webpack4 bootstarp in development mode.

```
/******/   (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
            ...
/******/    function hotCreateRequire(moduleId) {
/******/        var me = installedModules[moduleId];
/******/        if (!me) return __webpack_require__;
/******/        var fn = function(request) {
/******/            if (me.hot.active) {
/******/                if (installedModules[request]) {
                            // here use 'includes' not supported in es5 
/******/                    if (!installedModules[request].parents.includes(moduleId))
```

And my development enviroment is not chrome, it didn't support these new features.

So how can i solve it ?

Or I have to use webpack3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.prototype.includes - not transformed with babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462708/array-prototype-includes-not-transformed-with-babel) - you need a polyfill.

Comment: The code is produced by webpack, not my business code. And with webpack3, it can run without error.

Answer (score 0):

Sean from the webpack team. We had this reported (PS: this is something you should be reporting as a bug to our project, not general usage questions which should land on SO).

We have also opened [this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6764) which will aim to ensure that the runtime we produce is always backwards compatible ES5. (That link also has the link to merged PR where we have fixed this issue)